# Getting starting time of the particular date in dart

Tags: date, datetime, flutter, time, dart

Hi I am trying to get the start time as current date 12:00 AM as my fromTime

```
DateTime toTime= new DateTime.now();
DateTime fromTime= toTime.subtract(new Duration(days: 1));
```

By above I am getting fromTime value as curent time - 24hrs, 
but I want fromTime as current date 12 AM

output what I am getting is

```
2019-09-30 14:25:36.105 //toTime
2019-09-29 14:25:36.105 //fromTime
```

expected output:

```
2019-09-30 14:25:36
2019-09-30 00:00:00
```

help me out to get the above,Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you mean like this:

```dart
  DateTime toTime= new DateTime.now();
  DateTime fromTime= new DateTime(toTime.year, toTime.month, toTime.day);
  print(toTime);
  print(fromTime);
```

output:

```
2019-09-30 17:15:20.294
2019-09-30 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: yes, I am not getting how to get that time, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) it much simpler and is inspired by [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). It looks like you are trying to get the start day of `toTime` and set it to `fromTime`. Do the following

```
var toTime = Jiffy.now();
// or if you have a DateTime object
val toTime = Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(DateTime.now())

var fromTime = toTime.startOf(Units.DAY).dateTime; // This will return the start of day

print(toTime); // 2019-09-30 14:25:36.105
print(fromTime); // 2019-09-30 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension method. Extension methods are used to extend functionality to existing classes. Read more [here](https://dart.dev/language/extension-methods). Utilizing this we can create a get method:

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime get startOfDay {
    return DateTime(year, month, day);
  }
}
```

This can then be used to get the start of day:

```
final toTime = new DateTime.now();
final fromTime = toTime.startOfDay;
```

Comment: Nice and clean way !